# My code keeps segfaulting whenever I try to print strings

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, printf

I'm working on a game to run in the Linux Terminal. I've been working on a system to load in a map file, turn it into a string of custom structs, and then print the letter and color that the structures hold. The problem is that the code keeps segfaulting whenever I use `printf("%s", myString);`. The problem code is as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFLEN 3
#define DICLEN 3


/*a structure that holds basic tile info*/
typedef struct{
    char letter;
    char *color;
    char *name;
} tile;

/*a struture that holds general map info*/
typedef struct{
    const int mapHight;
    const int mapWidth;
    const int mapSize;
    const char *mapname;
} mapinfo;

/*dictionary that holds tiles*/
tile dic[DICLEN] = {
        {'T', "\033[38;5;2m", "Tree"},
        {' ', "\033[0m", "Path1"},
        {'\n', "\033[0m", "newLine"}
};

/*return a tile when given a name*/
tile dictionary(char *tileName){
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<DICLEN; i++){
        if ( (strcmp(tileName, dic[i].name) ) == 0){
                        goto END;
                }
    }
    goto ERROR;
    
    END:
    return dic[i];

    ERROR:
    fprintf(stderr, "that string is unreconnized");
    exit(-1);
}

/*gets map size to make into an array*/
mapinfo getMapSize(char *mapName){
    char mapFilePath[24] = "maps/";

    strcat(mapFilePath, mapName);
    char buffer[BUFFLEN];

    FILE *mapfile = fopen(mapFilePath, "r");
    
    for(int i; i < BUFFLEN; i++){
        buffer[i] = getc(mapfile); 
    }
    int mapWidth = atoi(buffer)+1;
    getc(mapfile);

    for(int i = 0; i < BUFFLEN; i++){
        buffer[i] = getc(mapfile);
    }
    int mapHight = atoi(buffer);

    int mapSize = mapHight * mapWidth;
    fclose(mapfile);
    
    mapinfo finalMap = {mapHight, mapWidth, mapSize, mapFilePath};
    return finalMap;
}

/*initalize map; put tiles into the map array*/
void mapInit(tile *mapArray, char *mapName){
    FILE *mapFile = fopen(mapName, "r");
    int i = 1, o = 0;
    char c;

    //this is to skip over the map size information
    for(;(c = getc(mapFile))!= '\n';){}

    for(;(c = getc(mapFile)) != EOF; i++){
        for(o = 0; o < DICLEN; o++){
            if(c == dic[o].letter){
                mapArray[i] = dictionary(dic[o].name);
            }
        }
        // un-comment this line for debug if needed
        //printf("%d\t%c%c\n",i, c, mapArray[i].letter);
    }

    fclose(mapFile);
}

int main(){
    mapinfo map1Info = getMapSize("map1.map");
    tile map1[map1Info.mapSize];
    mapInit(map1, map1Info.mapname);
    
    printf("%s%c\n", map1[0].color, map1[0].letter);

    return 0;
}
```

and the information I am trying to read (`maps/map1.map`) is this:

```
011 010
TT TT T TTT
T T TTT TTT
T TT TTT TT
TTT TTTT TT
T T TTT  TT
TT TT TT TT
TT TT TTT T
T TTT TT TT
T TT T T  T
TTT TT    T
```

and it should be printing a green T

Whenever I changed `printf("%s%c\n", map1[0].color, map1[0].letter);` to `printf("%c\n", map1[0].letter);` the code prints, but obviously, there is no longer color, and I'd rather have the color.
I've tried to turn the pointers in the tile structure into arrays, but the compiler gives me warnings and segfaults anyways.

additional notes: yes I know `char c` in `mapInit` shold be an int, as well that I have serveral nested for loops that need to be resolved. For most of this code, only enought though was put into it to make it work, not work well (although tips would be nice since I still don't know how to fix some of these issues).

edit: after running my code through a debugger (gdb) this is what I could find:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/iggoth/Desktop/Programs/AKnightsTale/Game 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-vec.S:126
126 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-vec.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) list
121 in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-vec.S
(gdb)
```

I didn't find out any other information

edit 2: after running backtrace command:

```
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-vec.S:126
126 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-vec.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-vec.S:126
#1  0x00007ffff7df1d31 in __vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7f95780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x555555556129 "%s%c\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffce70, 
    mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=0) at ./stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c:1517
#2  0x00007ffff7ddb79f in __printf (format=<optimized out>) at ./stdio-common/printf.c:33
#3  0x0000555555555906 in main () at Main.c:12
(gdb)
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger to see what's happening? It's the best way to track down logic errors and program flow. If you don't know how to use the debugger, there's no better time to start learning. The debugger is the best tool available to a coder.

Comment: PSA: Check the result of operations that commonly fail, like `fopen`. Don't *assume* everything is fine.

Comment: Also `char mapFilePath[24]` is a really tiny buffer. Why not `PATH_MAX` or something even more generous?

Comment: @KenWhite no I haven't, I do most of my work in the terminal and haven't looked much into terminal based debuggers. If there's one that you recommend I'll update with the results.

Comment: That would depend on the compiler/tool chain you're using, as well as the OS you're on. GDB seems to be pretty prevalent.

Comment: @tadman I don't plant for my game to be all that large, and won't need all to many levels. Even then, if I need to later I can change the the length later.

Comment: I notice that in `getMapSize` you read into `buffer` which has length `3`, but A. `i` is uninitialized, and B. even if it is initialized to zero, `buffer` would not be a null-terminated string, which `atoi` expects. Multiple points leading to undefined behaviour just there.

Comment: (Not the cause of your crash): You have too many `goto` statements and labels in function `dictionary()`.  Use `return dic[i];` in place of `goto END;` and you then don't need the label `ERROR` or the `goto ERROR;` statement, and you can fix the spelling of "unrecognized" and add a newline to the end of the message.  It would probably be a good idea to add the unrecognized tile name to the output — `fprintf(stderr, "%s(): string '%s' is not recognized\n", __func__, tileName);`.  Good job on reporting the error to `stderr`!

Comment: @Hogan It costs you almost nothing to use reasonably generous buffers like `255`, `1024` or `PATH_MAX`. Using something so incredibly tiny means wasting time later with a buffer overflow bug. `strcat` will gladly shoot you in the foot many times over if you're not particularly careful, or use tools like `strncat` in a more disciplined manner.

Comment: Incidentally,, when rewritten, you can use idiomatic `for (int i = 0; i < DICLEN; i++)` for the loop in `dictionary()`.  Also, I had to add `#define FALSE 0` and `#define TRUE 1` to the code to get it to compile.  I then run into "too many initializers" for the array of tiles — what is the FALSE/TRUE flag for?  However, this is a major improvement over yesterday's iteration of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77478181/15168) — 10K rep needed.

Comment: @tadman — I agreed with you up until you mentioned `strncat()`.  That's a function with an abhorrent, abnormal interface that is far too easy to misuse.

Comment: in gdb when it crashes run command 'backtrace' this will show you the full call stack back to the line/sub in your code

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I boiled down the code to only the functions and values that were important to reading a writing maps and character data. It seems I forgot to shorten the tile declarations that were tied to another variable in the `tile` struc. These were tied to an int called `walkable` for collision detection later on down the road.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Arguably a different flavour of pain and suffering. What approach do you recommend?

Comment: In `getMapSize()`, you need to initialize `i` in the loop: `for (int i = 0; i < BUFLEN; i++)`.  The `mapName` parameter to `mapInit()` should be `const char *mapName`.  You should always (but always!) check that `fopen()` succeeds — it is far too easy for it to fail, and using the null file pointer causes crashes.

Comment: @tadman: using `strncpy()` or `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.  If you know enough to use `strncat()` safely, you know enough not to need it and you can use the other functions safely — even `strncat()` because you will know there's enough space in the target for the null-terminator byte.

Comment: `mapInit` takes a `tile` pointer and a `char` pointer as parameters. However, the call in `main` passes a `tile` (not a pointer, so shouldn't compile) and a `char` pointer. `mapInit` then assigns to its first parameter as if the pointer were an array. None of this looks like it will initialise a `tile` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem I spotted.

In the code:

```
mapinfo getMapSize(char *mapName){
    char mapFilePath[24] = "maps/";
    :
    mapinfo finalMap = {mapHight, mapWidth, mapSize, mapFilePath};
    return finalMap;
}
```

`mapFilePath` is a local variable and you're putting a pointer to it into the `finalMap` object you're returning, so that will be dangling (the local var goes away when you return leaving the pointer invalid).

Not to say there aren't other problems -- the code looks like a recipe for dangling pointer problems.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the segmentation fault is likely that the `color` pointer was never initialised. Alternatively, it may be pointing at an object that has already been deallocated. Like Chris wrote, there are lots of potential dangling pointers.

The struct would be better defined to have its own array buffers.

```
static const int TILE_NAME_LENGTH = 16;

struct{
    char letter;
    char color[TILE_NAME_LENGTH];
    char name[TILE_NAME_LENGTH];
} tile;
```

When instantiating a `tile`, you would then call `memset` to set all values to zero (eg `memset(pTile, 0, sizeof(tile))`), unless you have initial values like you have in the `dic` array. That way, char arrays without an initial value are empty strings.

When copying the items, you would need a function for copying from a source `const tile *` to a target `tile *`. A simple `=` assignment would not be allowed if the members were arrays.